# Check application version in Catalina

Tags: catalina

I just upgraded to Catalina `10.15.7` coming from *High Sierra*.

On any previous MacOS release I can press space on any app on app drawer to show application version.

I'm positive they removed it in recent release since I can't view app version anymore.

Any other method to view app version?

Comment: What's an 'app drawer'? You mean the Dock? This is not a functionality I have ever been aware of. Cmd/I to Get Info is the accepted method, or using the 'app name' menu in the app itself > About [app name]

Comment: Not really the dock, I always have app folder in the docker which open like app drawer. Get info also now showing app version.
The idea is not open the app check the version.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're referring to. I've either never seen this feature, or switched it off the moment it was introduced.

Comment: Yes, could you supply a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: @Tetsujin He is probably talking about the [**stacks**](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/organize-files-in-stacks-mh35846/mac) feature on the right-hand side of the **Dock**.

Comment: @user3439894 - ah, yes, right. Thank you. I did switch that off, day one, then forgot it ever existed ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can usually see the version number of an Application in the Finder's Preview pane (most obviously seen in Column View, but also available in other views with View > Show Preview).

[image]

System Information's Applications panel will also show the Version numbers. (You may need to wait a bit while it collects the info.)

[image]

Individual apps can be checked with File > Get Info.

[image]

Comment: You're on Catalina right? Is there any permission I need to enable for this functionality? Something was off, I just upgraded my MacBook and the said functionality still here but not on my desktop.

Comment: These functions should be present on Big Sur, Catalina, Mojave, and several prior OS versions.